# Creating a debian package on CentOS

Tags: debian, centos6, packaging

I am using CentOS for development of a program which runs on Debian. 
In order to package the program I am accessing a debian VM. However, I would like to create the package directly from CentOS, using dpkg-buildpackage tool. Is there any option to install dpkg-buildpackage on CentOS?

Answer (score 1):

That won't help you much. The .deb build infrastructure pretty much depends on a lot of debian-specifics. So, your debian VM is probably the easiest way to go – or a debootstrap'ped chroot would probably work, too.

Comment: It's been æons, but the `debbootstrap`ped `chroot` did work some time age.

Comment: @BRFennPocock yeah, chroots have been getting less often discussed, although they are, in many ways, much easier to handle, less confusing and stable compared to the Docker'ing kids tend to do these days.